# reference error cannot find variable TinyMCE

Tags: air, tinymce, src, referenceerror

I am trying to run my tinyMCE.js from localhost

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

I am getting error ReferenceError: Can't find variable: tinyMCE

It works when i try to run tinyMCE.js from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
where tiny_mce is my root folder that contain tiny_mce.js
```

I can't figure out why

Comment: looks like your server (on localhost) is not configured properly

Comment: What should i do in order to configure it according to localhost?

Comment: difficult to say. can you access http://localhost/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js using your browser? what about  http://localhost/tinymce ?

Comment: yes i can access that js from localhost (localhost/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js) , but in my AIR application i am using HTMLLoader, inside of it tiny_mce.js loads. Is there anyway can i set application domain to localhost?

Comment: yan you make sure that document.domain is the same at all points of your application? if not there might be a problem with security

Answer (score -1):

If you are using npm, try `npm install tinymce`